# Postgres DB updates visible to Mapinfo Application

Tags: postgresql, mapinfo

I design a MapInfo 10.5 app that connects to a Remote Linux Server hosting a PostgreSQL DB. When starting the app I'm reading some tables from DB and create a local version of them that I work on it (query info, display thematic maps etc.). I'm using commit/refresh procedure to update info on DB. On the server hosting the DB I'm using another app (develop with Java) that updates the very same tables I'm using locally on MapInfo. Is there a method to be inform in MapInfo app when these changes take place on the server?

ex. I read in MapInfo table GSMCells from PostreSQL and working on it locally query or display some info.

```
"Server hdbc Link Table "SELECT  *  FROM  ""public"".""GSMCells""" Into GSMCells    File "C:\Temp\GSMCells"
```

Meanwhile a new version of GSMCells is available on the server. Me, as a user, I'm not aware of these change unless I'm doing a refresh:

```
"Server Refresh GSMCells"
```

Since I don't know when the new version is available and not willing to refresh periodically I will like to be informed when this is happening. Any idea how?